# Saving user credentials in a Windows application

Tags: .net, windows, security, authentication

Is there is a best practices way to store credentials in a .NET Windows application, be it be a built in API or just a recommend encryption algorithm?

Along the same lines as Tortoise SVN, Spotify and Skype.

**Edit:** My intention is to use a web service that returns a token from it's authentication service. The other services then accept that token as a parameter. However, the token expires after 30 minutes so storing the token itself it pointless for this task.

Comment: Just in case you haven't encountered it before: [Designing an Authentication System:
a Dialogue in Four Scenes](http://web.mit.edu/kerberos/www/dialogue.html) is a great article about Kerberos principles; I think it can be interesting in the context of creating your authentication service.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It appears that using [ProtectedData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata.aspx) (which wraps the [Windows Data Protection API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995355(loband).aspx)) is my best bet, as it has the option to encrypt based on the currently logged in user.

```
byte[] dataToEncrypt = new byte[] { ... };

// entropy will be combined with current user credentials
byte[] additionalEntropy = new byte { 0x1, 0x2, 0x3, 0x4 };

byte[] encryptedData = ProtectedData.Protect(
    dataToEncrypt, additionalEntropy, DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser);

byte[] decryptedData = ProtectedData.Unprotect(
    encryptedData, additionalEntropy, DataProtectionScope.CurrentUser);
```

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is never to store credentials, only Kerberos tokens... unfortunately, not every resource allows such authentication.

Answer (score 0):

There are a whole lot of [recomendations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms717799(VS.85).aspx) re passwords in MSDN. You're going to need to find a managed wrapper for [CryptProtectData](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380261(VS.85).aspx)

Comment: System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData *is* a managed wrapper for CryptProtectedData. See my answer above.